# How to create the Multiple template screens as in default Notification template in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, templates

[image: First Screen]

[image: Second Scren]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<template
    format="5"
    revision="3"
    name="Notification"
    description="Creates a new helper class that can show or cancel a        status bar notification."
    minApi="4">

    <category value="UI Component" />

    <dependency name="android-support-v4" revision="10" />

    <parameter
        id="className"
        name="Class Name"
        type="string"
        constraints="class|unique|nonempty"
        default="NewMessageNotification"
        help="The name of the notification helper class to create, e.g.    'NewMessageNotification'." />

    <parameter
        id="expandedStyle"
        name="Style when Expanded"
        type="enum"
        default="text"
        help="The expanded notification style to use for devices running Android 4.1 or later." >
        <option id="none">None</option>
        <option id="text">More text</option>
        <option id="picture">Picture</option>
        <option id="list">List</option>
    </parameter>

    <parameter
        id="moreActions"
        name="Show Additional Actions"
        type="boolean"
        default="true"
        help="If true, this notification will contain additional actions when expanded on devices running Android 4.1 or later." />

    <globals file="globals.xml.ftl" />
    <execute file="recipe.xml.ftl" />

    <thumbs>
        <thumb>template_notification_text_actions.png</thumb>
        <thumb expandedStyle="none">template_notification_none.png</thumb>
        <thumb expandedStyle="none" moreActions="true">template_notification_none_actions.png</thumb>
        <thumb expandedStyle="text">template_notification_text.png</thumb>
        <thumb expandedStyle="text" moreActions="true">template_notification_text_actions.png</thumb>
        <thumb expandedStyle="list">template_notification_list.png</thumb>
        <thumb expandedStyle="list" moreActions="true">template_notification_list_actions.png</thumb>
        <thumb expandedStyle="picture">template_notification_picture.png</thumb>
        <thumb expandedStyle="picture" moreActions="true">template_notification_picture_actions.png</thumb>
    </thumbs>

    <icons
        type="notification"
name="ic_stat_${camelCaseToUnderscore(className?replace('notification','','i'))}" />
</template>
```

These 2 screens are part of same `template.xml`. I can get the single screen `template.xml` like this or any other template. But I wish to create the template with multiple screens if possible.Is it possible to create more than one screen as in the notification template shown below?

PS: I tried using the notification template's `template.xml` and other resources such as `recipe.xml` and `globals.xml` but have no clue how they are creating two screens.

Comment: just a clarification, do you want to show 2 template on 1 notification?

Comment: I mean, the default Notification template have two screen for displaying template as shown above. I can create a single screen template. But I wish I could do something like default Notification template found in android studio. I wish I could more have more than one template to fill the input.

Comment: no, what is shown above is a single template only, it is an expandable notification. This will show when you have long text added in notification.

Comment: I am not talking about notification or expandable notification. https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/templates.html